# Sort by JSON field values

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table with json values like this:

**-Table 1**

```
id    |   name   |   data
------+----------+---------------
1     | Test     | {"city_id": 3, "email":"test@test.com", "city_name":"something"}
2     | Test 2   | {"city_id": 1, "email":"test2@test2.com", "city_name":"another"}
3     | Test 3   | {"city_id": 6, "email":"test3@test3.com", "city_name":"blahblah"}
```

Now I want `SELECT` records with `order by` `data.city_name`, so I use this code:

```
SELECT id, name, JSON_EXTRACT(data, 'city_name') AS cityName
FROM table1
ORDER BY cityName ASC
```

but this query cannot sort my records correctly !

P.S: `city_name` have UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Can you show us actual data, erroneous output and expected output?

Comment: try as :: SELECT ... JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.city_name') AS cityName...

Comment: MySQL handles strings used in JSON context using the utf8mb4_bin collation, so accents and case are sensitive.

Answer (score 36):

you do not seem to be using [JSON_EXTRACT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) properly, try with:

```
SELECT id, name, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.city_name') AS cityName 
FROM demo ORDER BY cityName ASC
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dDuw3sbJS46gJ3soUHbfw3/0)

Answer (score 11):

I usually [cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html) the JSON value ([->>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)) to the correct type in order to sort properly:

```
SELECT id, name, data->>'$.city_name' AS cityName
FROM table1
ORDER BY CAST(cityName AS CHAR) ASC
```

Otherwise, you end up sorting as a blob (binary), which are treated as binary strings (byte strings) and thus they have the binary character set and collation, and comparison and sorting are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values ([ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)).

Answer (score 7):

the easiest way in my opinion

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable order by data->"$.city_name" desc
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since other answers will add an extra field to the results

Answer (score 1):

Check This.

```
SELECT Id ,name,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,'city_name":"',-1),'"',1) as CITY
FROM tempjson
order by SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,'city_name":"',-1),'"',1)
```

OutPut :

[image]