# How to use mysql cast json?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to sort the prices in Json from small to large, but I think I made something wrong where exactly could I make a mistake?

```php
    public function kitaplik($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('kitaplik_isbn', $id);
        $this->db->order_by("CAST(json_object('kitaplik_ifiyat', kitaplik_json) AS DECIMAL(9,2))");
        $query = $this->db->get('kitaplik');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**kitaplik->kitaplik_json**

```
{"kitap_fiyat":25.46,"kitap_ifiyat":12}
```

I have many products in the "kitaplik" table and the prices of these products are in json. I would like to sort these products from small to large using CAST Decimal. But I have to sort by taking the prices in the "kitaplik_ifiyat" section in json. How can I do this?

Comment: but what is the mistake? what is the expected output, how does your json column look like? That's beside of how many records do you expect to be returned? You are querying for an $id, is this a unique index?, if so....well

Comment: @Vickel does not sort data from small to large. It outputs normal data.

Comment: yes! but what does the `where`clause, could it be that it limits the returned record set to one? that's why I asked, what is the json column look like and what is the expected output

Comment: @Vickel My English isn't very good so I can't understand you very much. The data output is as follows. It's not sorting properly.


24.48 TL 
---------
24.19 TL
---------
12.00 TL

Comment: no problem with your English, just please edit your question with *relevant* details. If you look at your question and the last comment now, could you find an answer yourself? why is the sort order in your comment incorrect? You need to add this to your question, please

Comment: look at this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137881/sort-by-json-field-values

Comment: @Vickel I tried to be more detailed

Answer (score 1):

this is how I solved the problem

```php
    public function kitaplik($id)
    {
        $this->db->select("kitaplik_json, kitaplik_isbn, JSON_EXTRACT(kitaplik_json, '$.kitaplik_ifiyat') AS fiyat");
        $this->db->where('kitaplik_isbn', $id);
        $this->db->order_by('fiyat ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get('kitaplik');
        return $query->result();
    }
```