# sort a JSON array with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to register for youtube API statistics as JSON data to its proper database. I figured out listing whole data so far,
but I'm not able to list and sort the individual data, which stands for "dislikeCount", descending from more to less.

The JSON data I mentioned in "$ Row ['page_content']" section is below. and I want the "dislikeCount" data to be sorted from large to small.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Database page_content**

```
{
    "kind":"youtube#video",
    "etag":"LVLEiwEdUU043rY6JqiUrm7FmYY",
    "id":"IMiBrszc40s",
    "statistics":{
        "viewCount":"6416534",
        "likeCount":"26553",
        "dislikeCount":"1862",
        "favoriteCount":"0",
        "commentCount":"987"
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
$query = $db->from('pages')->orderBy('page_id', 'ASC')->all();

if ($query) {

    foreach ($query as $row) {

        $json = json_decode($row['page_content'], true);
        $videoView = $json['statistics']['viewCount'];
        $videoLike = $json['statistics']['likeCount'];
        $videoComment = $json['statistics']['commentCount'];

        echo $videoView;
        echo $videoLike;
        echo $videoComment;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you start and end the PHP tags so much? There is no need for that. You even have multiple lines of PHP between single tags, so you already know this is possible. Besides this, your question is very unclear. I'm not sure what you want us to help you with.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Kaan. I'm sorry, but, like @GrumpyCrouton, I don't understand what you want to do. I suggest you to edit your question to clarify it! :)

Comment: We're [I'm] glad to be here. You are right I am a little novice, I may not have been able to express myself. I hope you understand. thank you

Comment: Is there really a quote missing in `orderBy('page_id, 'ASC')->all()`

Comment: $page_content <<< I'm talking about the json data, I don't understand what you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you have a database table `pages`. This table has a JSON column, `page_content`, which contains the JSON as you've specified. Now you want to sort the `pages` based on the `pages.page_content.statistics.dislikeCount`?

If you're using MySQL or PostgreSQL, then you can order the resultset in the SQL query directly. For example, for MySQL (untested, as I don't have mysql running locally right now):

```sql
SELECT * FROM pages
ORDER BY page_id, page_content->"$.statistics.dislikeCount"
```

If SQL is not an option, you can use PHP's [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Comment: Is it possible to order by json over sql?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137881/sort-by-json-field-values

Comment: yes I have a "pages" table and it is present in my "page_content" column. but how can I access the json value in this orderby?

Comment: did but sorting is wrong: s or rather, no sequence: s